# Make a widget show on a specified Label on blogger

Tags: blogger

I run a Blogger blog goofyanimals.com and need to make a widget show on a specified Label only on my Blogger blog.  I know nothing about coding.  I have created a text widget named 'Funny Animals' and need for it to only show on the 'Funny Animals' Label.  I am attaching some code which may help with this matter...

```
<b:section-contents id='sidebar-right-1'>
  <b:widget id='Text2' locked='false' title='Funny Animals' type='Text'>
    <b:widget-settings>
      <b:widget-setting name='content'>Funny Animals text widget</b:widget-setting>
    </b:widget-settings>
    <b:includable id='main'>
  <!-- only display title if it's non-empty -->
  <b:if cond='data:title != &quot;&quot;'>
    <h2 class='title'><data:title/></h2>
  </b:if>
  <div class='widget-content'>
    <data:content/>
  </div>

  <b:include name='quickedit'/>
</b:includable>
  </b:widget>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its possible BUT you will have to add some code into the blog widget and also use some css...

Basically, you must hide the widget and only make it visible when the right label is present in the post by taking advantage of the `<b:loop values='data:post.labels' var='label'>`.

Since there are so many blogger templates, including some with more modern coding, this will be easier if you can tell me wich template are you working on... or look if you can find the loop label line.

So, first you must hide the widget, in this case put on your CSS:

```
#Text2 {
   display: none;
}
```

Then look for `<b:loop values='data:post.labels' var='label'>` and below this line, add the following:

```
<b:if cond='data:label.name == &quot;Funny Animals&quot;'>
<style>
#Text2 {
   display: block;
}
</style>
</b:if>
```

That will make the hidden widget be visible only when that label is present in the post.

Comment: Hi, many thanks for your reply.  My blog is https://www.goofyanimals.com and I am using the Simple Theme as indicated on the Footer of my blog.  I know nothing about coding and simply run a blog with no technical abilities apart from posting and editing on the admin side.

Comment: Yeah, that's a simple template like the name says. It should be easy for you to follow my answer above. Remember that while editing the HTML of the template, you can use the search by clicking anywhere and using CTRL+F (I use Firefox, not sure if any other browser works the same)...

Comment: Since you say you have little knowledge about coding, check this article about editing the template: https://www.talkofweb.com/how-to-edit-template-in-blogger-step-by-step-guide-with-images/  Maybe it can be helpful for you too...

Comment: Hi Osvaldo,  Where exactly do I add this the code: #Text2 {
   display: none;
}

Comment: That part is to put in your CSS styles. Usually between <b:skin> and </b:skin>...

Comment: Hi Osvaldo,  Sorry for the delay.  Are you able to send me a screenshot showing where to place all the relevant code?  I have put much time on creating my blog and I am worried that I might do something wrong?  I would be very grateful if you continued help.  Resolving this problem will help so much with SEO once I managed to resolve the issue and replicate it with all my Labels

Comment: ...  I did try adding the code but it did not work.  The widget disappears on the index page but does not reappear on the Funny Animals label.  A screenshot would help as I do not know if I added the code correctly in the right place.  I did find the  <b:skin> and </b:skin> but there is much code in between and don't know if I add the first bit of code in the right place there....

Comment: I've tested with that template and it works. From my testing it might need more work depending where exactly you want to display the widget. Meaning that with the code on my answer above it shows where ever the selected label is present, either homepage, item page or index page. Important details: #Text2 is the id from your question example code, it must be changed if that changes from your example. Assuming that Test2 id the right ID, in your template you'll find the Variable definitions almost at the beginning of your HTML.

Comment: After that you'll find the CSS styles for body and html body, and h2 and so on. You can put that first part of my answer somewhere next to any of those. It will be easier to find in case you need to remove it or change it later. Then by using the search tool, find the <b:loop values='data:post.labels' var='label'> and place the 2nd part of my answer code. Important: The label MUST be written exactly as it is on the blog posts. Let me know if you need more help and I'll try to make some screenshots for you.

Comment: Also, let me know if you only want the widget display on some type of pages... i.e. item or index pages...